# Multivalue SIngle Key Dictionary in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following dictionary in Python. I want to access the 2nd value and assign it to a new var new time. Im trying to do it using list however I am unable to arrive at the answer I need

```
exampledict = {
        "a": ["url1", "file_name1"],
        "b": ["url2", "filename2"],
        "d": ["url4", "filename4"],
        "c": ["url3", "filename3"],}


for key, value in exampledict.items():
        url = value[0]
        filename = value[1]
        # do stuff with url and filename

# later:
# I want to do something will all my filenames without getting them again from the dict.
```

So the actual result would be storing filename is 4 diff variables each time so that I can access it. Im trying to do this using an emptylist and then extending.But doing that gives me four seprate files in list format rather then one list containing all the 4 files (so i can access using index).Im new to programming and would appreciate a step by step help and what logic mistake I have made

Kindly ignore any syntax errors in the code

Comment: Actually I want to store the filenames in different variables  for later comparison using pandas.Here Im able to extract the filenames but I dont know how to store them in different variables

Comment: Yeah.  As you can see in my post thats what I was trying to do. However I was wondering whether  .extend method can be used here to attach the filenames to a empty list as I dont want another for loop

Answer (score 1):

No need to extend, simply fill a list iteratively:

```
exampledict = {
        "a": ["url1", "file_name1"],
        "b": ["url2", "filename2"],
        "d": ["url4", "filename4"],
        "c": ["url3", "filename3"],}

filenames = []
for key, value in exampledict.items():
        url = value[0]
        filename = value[1]

        # do more stuff
        print ("In loop", url, filename)

        filenames.append(filename)


print(filenames)
```

Output:

```
In loop url1 file_name1
In loop url2 filename2
In loop url4 filename4
In loop url3 filename3
['file_name1', 'filename2', 'filename4', 'filename3']
```

If you are just interested in the filenames, you can extract them directly:

```
fns = [filename for _,filename in exampledict.values()]
```

Comment: Thanks for that.Very helpful.I cant upvote you as I am new

Comment: @aks Good thing I helped you get unstuck.  You might want to lookup a good tutorial, f.e. here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ and follow it.

Answer (score 0):

you missed a coma in your dictionary in "d" row,

try this:

```
urls = []
files = []

exampledict = {
        "a": ["url1", "file_name1"],
        "b": ["url2", "filename2"],
        "d": ["url4", "filename4"],
        "c": ["url3", "filename3"],}


for key, value in exampledict.items():
        url = value[0]
        urls.append(url)
        filename = value[1]
        files.append(filename)
```

now you acces the info in the arrays urls and files like:

```
print(urls[0])... print(urls[3])
print(files[0])...print(files[3])
```

Comment: Thanks Very helpful.Il be unable to upvote as Im new